# Using HDF5 datasets (not to be confused with HDFS) as targets in luigi

Tags: python, h5py, hdf, luigi

From my read of the docs, luigi is designed to work with text files or raw binaries as Targets. I am trying to build a luigi workflow for an existing processing pipeline that uses HDF5 files (for their many advantages) using h5py on a regular file system.  Some tasks in this workflow do not create a whole new file, but rather add new datasets to an existing HDF file.  Using h5py I would read a dataset with:

```
hdf = h5py.File('filepath','r')
hdf['internal/path/to/dataset'][...]
```

write a dataset with:

`hdf['internal/path/to/dataset'] = np.array(data)`

and test if a dataset in the HDF file exists with this line:

`'internal/path/to/dataset' in hdf`

My question is, is there a way to adapt luigi to work with these types of files? 
My read of luigi docs makes me think I may be able to either subclass `luigi.format.Format` or perhaps subclass `LocalTarget` and make a custom 'open' method.  But I can't find any examples on how to implement this. Many thanks to any suggestions!

Comment: `h5py` is an interface to `HDF5` files.  `HDFS` is something entirely different (a JAVA based file system).  I see items the `luigi` docs about `HDFS`, but nothing about `HDF5`.

Comment: How about modeling on one of the database modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[d6tflow](https://github.com/d6t/d6tflow) has a HDF5 pandas implementation and can easily be extended to save data other than pandas dataframes.

```
import d6tflow
from d6tflow.tasks.h5 import TaskH5Pandas
import pandas as pd

class Task1(TaskH5Pandas):
    def run(self):
        df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10)})
        self.save(df)

class Task2(d6tflow.tasks.TaskCachePandas):

    def requires(self):
        return Task1()

    def run(self):
        df = self.input().load()
        # use dataframe from HDF5

d6tflow.run([Task2])
```

To see https://d6tflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/targets.html#writing-your-own-targets on how to extend.

Comment: I have yet to implement this but this is exactly what I am looking for thanks!